# Are there other way of ignoring an Error in VB?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

Are there any shorter way of ignoring an error?

This is my code

```
Try
     Directory.Delete(FolderName, True)
Catch
End Try
```

It simply tries to delete a folder if it exist. If It doesn't see the folder an error will occur which is what I'm trying to ignore. It is taking space and makes it cumbersome to scroll through the code

I have used `On Error Resume Next` but it seems to ignore all error on the method and it looks like I'm using it wrong.

It would be appreciated if someone tell a shorter way of trying to delete a directory without worrying about null/directory not found exceptions

Thanks!

Comment: The classic way to revert from `On Error Resume Next` is to use `On Error GoTo 0`.  I don't think that would have much benefit, though... it only saves one line, and it's very much a legacy coding style.  I wouldn't expect you to have a lot of lines like this one where you want to effectively fire and forget. I don't think it's a bad thing for them to stand out as unusual, because they *should be* unusual.

Comment: An exception is exceptional, meaning it shouldn't happen, but `Try..Catch` is there to handle those exceptional cases. Exceptions should not be built into logic whenever possible. That being said, if everyone coded this way, then [FileNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception?view=net-6.0) would be unnecessary, but still, we have it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always code with the intention of preventing errors from happening, so I would have written that as

```
If Directory.Exists(folderName) Then
   Directory.Delete(folderName, True)
End If
```

That said, I encourage you to get rid off the the attitude to "ignore errors". Instead embrace exception handling with `Try/Catch/End Try`, as it finally let's you specifically handle error prone lines of code, which was a nightmare to deal with in old VB6.

The IDE also provides code folding for `Try/Catch/End Try` blocks, so if you feel they're taking away too much space, fold 'em!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Try Catch is an eyesore for single line codes especially if it is the one you needed. 
_"I always code with the intention of preventing errors from happening"_
I'll keep this In mind. Thanks!

Comment: The existence of a directory does not automatically mean that it can be deleted (permissions, file locks, ...). This can still throw an exception.

Comment: Also, the existence of the directory at the time you test it does not guarantee its continued existence at the time you try to delete it.  In some cases, it can lead to a better user experience to test first, but the race condition fundamentally means you always need to have error handling on file operations.

Comment: @dbasnett: Not sure why you changed `If Directory.Exists(folderName) = True` to `If Directory.Exists(folderName)`. Sure, it's technically the same, but I always prefer to be explicit/"outspoken" in my code, so that there are few changes that me or someone else makes a false assumption about what a line of code does.

Comment: @HelO'Ween the only thing that can appear between the If and the Then is a boolean so what other assumption could be made?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method and call it where you want to try to delete a folder. This way you always only have one line.

```
Sub TryDeleteFolder(folderName As String)
    Try
        Directory.Delete(folderName, True)
    Catch 
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: For me, "Try" implies that it will return whether it succeeded (see e.g. `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` in the .NET Framework).  I use something like "fireandforget" if I don't care if it succeeds.